# Need For-loop to allow user to exit

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm fairly new to python, so I'm aware that my code is a bit unsightly.
Essentially, I'm making a mock data base for a class course search. I'm attempting to allow the user to enter "exit" to leave the prompt, or to simply enter another course that will give them the direct information they need.

I've already attempted a while loop as well as priming the loop, but I'm a bit stumped as to how I would configure the code. Thus far, this is the closest I've got this to work, but obviously the "break" will only allow one extra iteration of the prompt, rather than allowing the user to enter information as many times as they'd like.

```
courseInfo = {"CS101": {"room": "3004", "Name": "Haynes", "Time": "8:00 a.m."}, "CS102": {"room": "4501", "Name": "Alvarado", "Time": "9:00 a.m."}, 
    "CS103": {"room": "6755", "Name": "Rich", "Time": "10:00 a.m."}, "NT110": {"room": "1244", "Name": "Burke", "Time": "11:00 a.m."}, 
"CM241": {"room": "1411", "Name": "Lee", "Time": "1:00 p.m."} }

courseInfo = {k.lower(): v for k, v in courseInfo.items()} 

for courseNumber in courseInfo:    
    courseNumber = input("\nEnter the course number: ").lower()
    print("\nThe course information for coourse # ",courseNumber, "is as follows:")
    print("Room #:", courseInfo[courseNumber] ["room"])
    print("Instructor: ",courseInfo[courseNumber] ["Name"])
    print("Time: ", courseInfo[courseNumber] ["Time"])
    done = input("\nEnter the course number or enter exit to leave: ")
    if done != "exit":
    print("\nThe course information for coourse # ",courseNumber, "is as follows:")
    print("Room #:", courseInfo[courseNumber] ["room"])
    print("Instructor: ",courseInfo[courseNumber] ["Name"])
    print("Time: ", courseInfo[courseNumber] ["Time"])
    break
else:
    print("Program terminated normally")
    break
```

Comment: The indentation is off

Answer (score 0):

Using a while loop:

```
def get_input():
    return input("Course nr or exit: ")

user_input = get_input()
while user_input.lower() != 'exit':
    print("Some info: ", courseInfo.get(user_input, "course not found"))
    user_input = get_input()
```

This assigns the input to `user_input` and while this is not equal to `'exit'` it will first print out the germane information and then reassign `user_input` to the next input, which it'll then check again.

Notice that I modified the dictionary access. Using `dict.get(key[, default])` you can prevent `KeyError`s. If the first argument to `dict.get(key[, default])` isn't in `dict`, it will return `None` or the `default` argument if given.
If you wanted to print some info about all the available courses when the user inputs an invalid course number, you could use an `if` statement like this:

```
if user_input in courseInfo:  # checks if courseInfo has a key user_input
    print("Some info:", courseInfo[user_input])  # if it does, print the relevant info
else:  # otherwise:
    print("These are the available courses:", ', '.join(courseInfo.keys()))  # print out the available courses (or whatever you want)
```

Also, be careful to use `for ... else` or `while ... else` loops. This syntax is pretty unique to Python and can often lead to confusion because there are two perfectly reasonable but mutually exclusive assumptions a programmer may make about when the `else`-block is actually entered.

Answer (score 0):

```
courseInfo = {"CS101": {"room": "3004", "Name": "Haynes", "Time": "8:00 a.m."}, "CS102": {"room": "4501", "Name": "Alvarado", "Time": "9:00 a.m."}, 
    "CS103": {"room": "6755", "Name": "Rich", "Time": "10:00 a.m."}, "NT110": {"room": "1244", "Name": "Burke", "Time": "11:00 a.m."}, 
"CM241": {"room": "1411", "Name": "Lee", "Time": "1:00 p.m."} }

# Use this to keep the loop going
exit_flag = False

courseNumber = input("\nEnter the course number: ").strip().upper()
while not exit_flag:
    # Always assume the user will enter something not in the dict
    course = courseInfo.get(courseNumber, None)
    if course:
        print("\nThe course information for course # ",courseNumber, "is as follows:")
        print("Room #:", courseInfo[courseNumber] ["room"])
        print("Instructor: ",courseInfo[courseNumber] ["Name"])
        print("Time: ", courseInfo[courseNumber] ["Time"])
    else:
        print("\nCourse not found")

    courseNumber = input("\nEnter another course number or enter exit to leave: ").strip().upper()
    if courseNumber == "EXIT":
        exit_flag = True
```